# Would namespace1.classname.cs a good idea for a c# file? Otherwise, how can I get better ideas instead of this?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

at the moment im trying around to update my Knowledge about c# with NET 7.0 using the mvvm model, like reading about folder structure and so on. I'm using VS 2022 with ReSharper Extension.
So I'm making a models folder like that:

- Models

  - Interfaces => namespace Models.Interfaces*
  - Folder1 => namespace Models.Folder1*
    But what if I:
- Only have one file which is kind of redundant to put it in a separate folder?
- Dont want to have my Interfaces folder mixed up with model subfolders?
  If I create a file Folder1.Class1.cs I get kind of namespace warnings about it, also seems it not to be something VS 2022 is expecting bcs its forgetting to add the .cs ending to the created file. But bcs the "new" c# reminds me sometimes of Typescript or PHP I got the Idea to do so, also do I hate redundant folders like putting the models in some kind of "models" folder in a Models folder when there is no other kind of models in it. I know its kind of funny, but I'm trying and also autistic and sensitive to this.
  Could you tell me how to handle this?

Best regards and thx for answer

Expected namespace

- Models

  - Models.Interfaces
  - Models.Folder1
  - Models.Alias.Class1

Comment: Unless you're on an extraordinary SKU of Windows or Visual Studio, it's not like you're paying for folders. And having a folder structure that matches your namespace structure is the most straightforward way to ensure others understand the structure, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to have namespaces that match your folder structure.

It's much easier for everyone who will use the code to find everything if you do so. VS 2022 even has a "sync namespaces" feature that automatically renames any namespaces that do not match the folder structure.

If you only have a single file, in a folder it's fine to move it out into the higher folder but the namespace should still match the folder structure.

It's not much of a problem to mix interfaces and other types of classes within a folder if there is only a few but as the number increases it's best to give them separate folders.